# Display all dates between (01/01/2015) to today in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Here is what I have.

```
with 
a as
(select 1 as k, to_date('01/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as temp from dual),
b as
(select 1 as k, sysdate as t from dual)

select * from a
join b on a.k = b.k
where a.temp between a.temp and b.t
```

Now, I want to display all the days between those two dates.

How do I generate it?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're SO close!

```
with 
a as
(select 1 as k, to_date('01/01/2015', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as temp from dual),
b as
(select 1 as k, sysdate as t from dual)
select a.temp + level - 1 result from a          --> this
join b on a.k = b.k
where a.temp between a.temp and b.t
connect by level <= b.t - a.temp + 1;            --> this
```

Result is

```
RESULT                                                                          
----------                                                                      
01/01/2015                                                                      
02/01/2015                                                                      
03/01/2015                                                                      
04/01/2015 

<snip>

28/10/2019
29/10/2019
30/10/2019
31/10/2019

1765 rows selected.

SQL>
```